# Spring Batch not deserialising dates

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-batch, jackson2

I'm adding an object in the JobExecution context of spring batch, which contains an `Instant` field.

It's getting serialised as follows:

```
{
  "startFrom": {
    "nano": 0,
    "epochSecond": 1541116800
   }
 }
```

However, Spring Batch doesn't seem to be able to deserialise it.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to deserialize the execution context
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:325)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:309)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:667)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:657)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:688)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:756)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.getExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:112)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer.getJobExecutionDependencies(SimpleJobExplorer.java:202)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer.getJobExecutions(SimpleJobExplorer.java:83)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethod
```

When doing some research I see that Jackson has a `JavaTimeModule` to serialise/deserialise `Instant` and other date classes.
However, in the `Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer` class, it creates the `ObjectMapper` as follows, not registering the right module:

```
public Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer() {
    this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    this.objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
    this.objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
    this.objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping();
    this.objectMapper.registerModule(new JobParametersModule());
}
```

Is there a reason for Spring Batch not to use the autowired ObjectMapper? Or a reason for them not to register the `JavaTimeModule`?
Is there maybe a workaround this issue?

Thanks!

Edit:

I've found how to overwrite this object mapper:

```
  @Bean
  public JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()).findAndRegisterModules();

    Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer defaultSerializer = new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer();
    defaultSerializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    factory.setSerializer(defaultSerializer);
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
  }
```

However, even with this, the issue persists.

Comment: This really isn't a Spring Batch issue since we just delegate to Jackson and however that is configured.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me. I am extending Mahmoud Ben Hassine's answer above which didn't work for Nicolas Widart. (I don't have enough reputation to just comment).

```
@Bean
public BatchConfigurer configurer(DataSource dataSource, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
  ObjectMapper objectMapper) {

    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource) {
        final Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer serializer = new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer();

        @Override
        protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
            serializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

            JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
            factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
            factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
            factory.setSerializer(serializer);
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factory.getObject();
        }

        @Override
        protected JobExplorer createJobExplorer() throws Exception {
            serializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

            JobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactoryBean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
            jobExplorerFactoryBean.setSerializer(serializer);
            jobExplorerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            jobExplorerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
            return jobExplorerFactoryBean.getObject();
        }
    };
}
```

(I have defined an `ObjectMapper` bean in another `@Configuration` class.) The important thing here is to also override the `createJobExplorer()` method and set the correct `ExecutionContextSerializer` there, as this method will call `getTarget()` on the `JobExplorerFactoryBean`, which will set a vanilla `ExecutionContextSerializer` if there is none set and which causes the error you described.

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed is the default initialization of the serializer. You can override it by providing a custom object mapper that you pre-configure with the modules you need. Here is an example:

```
@Bean
public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = null; // configure the object mapper as required
    Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer serializer = new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer();
    serializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

    JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setSerializer(serializer);
    // set other properties on the jobRepositoryFactoryBean
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed thank you, I've done this too just before I saw your comment. I've updated my question accordingly. Even with this override, it does not properly deserialise dates.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Spring batch now has a fix that allows you to customise your `ObjectMapper` while also getting all of the default setup that `Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerialier` does internally after this issue was addressed: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2828.

The fix is in `4.2.0` which at time of writing is currently at `RC1`.

**Original answer**

I've noticed similar problems. I need to customise `ObjectMapper` to add `KotlinModule` for dealing with kotlin data classes. Unfortunately, the way `Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer` is currently written is not very extensible. As you have seen from the default `ObjectMapper` that was created there are some defaults that were added, including a fix for deserialisation issues with job parameters: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2680.

The `JobParametersModule` they setup is a `private` class and as such we cannot setup `ObjectMapper` with the same features and add to it.

I have raised an issue for this in Jira: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2828

The dirty workaround until this is fixed is to copy and paste the source code for `JobParmetersModule` so you can register the same in your override.

Answer (score 0):

On the topic at hand through the use of all the above answers

for me what worked in order to use the Jackson instance that had the module for

`jackson-datatype-jsr310 : support for Java 8 Date & Time API type`

```
@Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {
        return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().findModulesViaServiceLoader(true);
    }
```

was the following

Please note the fact that I am also having to override the getTransactionManager() and due to the fact that I am using JPA I also have to set the Isolation Level For Create to `ISOLATION_DEFAULT`

```
factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_DEFAULT");
```

:

```
 @Bean
    public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(DataSource dataSource, EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource) {

            final Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer serializer = new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer();

            @Override
            public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
                JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
                transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
                transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
                return transactionManager;
            }

            @Override
            public JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {

                // customize serializer
                serializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
                JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
                factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
                factory.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
                factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_DEFAULT");
                factory.setSerializer(serializer);
                // set other properties on the factory bean
                factory.afterPropertiesSet();
                return factory.getObject();
            }

           @Override
            protected JobExplorer createJobExplorer() throws Exception {
                serializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

                JobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactoryBean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
                jobExplorerFactoryBean.setSerializer(serializer);
                jobExplorerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
                jobExplorerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
                return jobExplorerFactoryBean.getObject();
            }
        };
    }
```