# How do you use Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer to add in trusted classes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch and Spring Boot and am having a problem when deserializing UUIDs as Jackson reports they are not a trusted class. According to the Spring docs I can add it to the list of trusted classes at construction time:

"Implementation that uses Jackson2 to provide (de)serialization. By default, this implementation trusts a limited set of classes to be deserialized from the execution context. If a class is not trusted by default and is safe to deserialize, you can add it to the base set of trusted classes at construction time or provide an explicit mapping using Jackson annotations"

However there are no examples that I can find. I have tried the following but it doesn't make any difference:

```
@Bean
ExecutionContextSerializer executionContextSerializer() {
  return new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer("java.util.UUID");
}
```

Any idea how to do it?

**EDIT**
I tried Luca Liechti's solution in this post
[Spring Batch not deserialising dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53116676/spring-batch-not-deserialising-dates)
which allowed the deserialization of UUIDs however it caused another issue with converting a List to an ArrayList

Comment: ` it caused another issue with converting a List to an ArrayList`: A fix has been included in v4.3.2 to support that by default: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3830. Is this what you are looking for? Which version of Spring Batch do you use? Please update the question with your specific issue.

Comment: 4.3.2 is the version, I got round the whole issue by wrapping the UUID in an Id class and adding the @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS) annotation, but it's not ideal